# windows forms maximize/minimize/close buttons in title bar flicker

Tags: c++, windows, forms, flicker

I've made a plugin for Winamp which is a simple dll file that starts a Windows Forms GUI (C++). But when I move the mouse coursor over the maximize/minimize/close button in the title bar, these buttons flicker. 
Enabling the double buffer didn't work. (http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/39858)

Do you have another hint?

Thanks,
Martin

edit: I don't handle WM_NCMOUSEMOVE ...

edit2: or do you have an idea for a work around?

Comment: Do you handle WM_NCMOUSEMOVE?